# The RPC server is unavailable. 0x800706ba (WIN32: 1722 RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE)

Tags: windows, server, active-directory, certificate

I want to request a certificate on a standalone certification authority, and I have the next issue:
The RPC server is unavailable. 0x800706ba (WIN32: 1722 RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE)
I did these tasks, but the problem follows:

> - Disable the firewall on the CA (OK)
> - Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem –ComputerName (OK)
> - netstat -ano | find "135" (OK)
> - sc query Winmgmt and sc query rpcss (OK)
> - service Remote Procedure Call (RPC) is running (OK)
> - Test-NetConnection IP -port 135 (OK)
> - Test-NetConnection IP -port 49703 (WARNING: TCP connect to (IP : 49703) failed)
> - Event Viewer: Security (The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server
>   application with CLSID {D99E6E74-FC88-11D0-B498-00A0C90312F3} and
>   APPID {D99E6E74-FC88-11D0-B498-00A0C90312F3} to the user SID
>   (S-1-5-21-2052401950-75243191-622671684-9855) from address LocalHost
>   (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID
>   (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the
>   Component Services administrative tool.)
> - Add Domain Users, Domain Controllers, Domain Computers groups to Certificate Service DCOM Access
> - Update the DCOM security settings on the server with the CA role (certutil -setreg SetupStatus -SETUP_DCOM_SECURITY_UPDATED_FLAG / net
>   stop certsvc & net start certsvc)
> - Nltest /Server:dc01 /query (OK)
> - Certutil -ping (OK)

Thank so much.

Comment: I have the same problem (Win 2016 DC) while setting up AD FS. Any resolution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to please check the **TCP RPC Dynamic Ports** on the client side. The RPC dynamic port range is **49152-65535**. Also ensure that **TCP Port 135** is also opened along with the RPC Dynamic Ports. These ports should be open outbound from the system requesting the certificate from the **Certification Authority** to the Domain controller and the CA Server.

Also, please check whether **'Windows Remote Management'** service is set to **'Manual'** or not as well as it should be started. Please ensure the same status about **'Background Intelligence Transfer Service'** also on the system requesting the certificate. Once, the above said provisions are done, your issue while requesting a certificate should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the errors `Invalid pointer 0x80004003 (-2147467261 E_POINTER)` when accessing the server through `https://<CA-IP>/certsrv` URL from a remote client (macOS with Chrome) and the error `The RPC server is unavailable. 0x800706ba (WIN32: 1722 RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE)` when accessing the server locally through `https://localhost/certsrv` (Server 2012 R2 with IE). My test results was the same then yours - everything seems to be OK, as expected. The solution I found was logging in as my user into the AD CS via RDP, opened `certmgr.msc`, right click on `Personal` folder > `All Tasks`> `Request New Certificate`. After that, I exported the certificate with the private key for my own needs.

**Edit:** Which also worked for me was requesting the certificate accessing the server locally through `https://localhost/certsrv` (Server 2012 R2 with IE) but I had added the URL `https://localhost` to the IE **Trusted Sites** list. Also notice that the certificate will be requested by using the AD User `CN`. You can export the certificate and it's private key from the machine (optional) by using `certmgr.msc` > **Personal** > **Certificates**.

Please do not use other browsers or OSes to request a certificate, as the page uses ActiveX that is only supported on IE (I believe it may work into Edge mode). One of consequences of requesting a certificate using another browser is that the `Key Strenght` field can't be selected and the error `Invalid pointer 0x80004003 (-2147467261 E_POINTER)` is thrown when requesting the User Certificate.

I was also receiving the Event Viewer Log ID **36874** (`An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server. The SSL connection request has failed.`) on **System** logs when requesting the certificate through the Server 2012 R2 IE browser, but I noticed it didn't prevented the certificate to be requested if IE was setup to disable TLS 1.2 and use TLS 1.1 instead. But if you're receiving this event log and want to fix it, you can check the links below to enable TLS 1.2 into Windows Vista/7/Server 2008 (R2)/Server 2012 (R2):

1. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392#bkmk_easy
2. https://improveandrepeat.com/2019/10/how-to-activate-tls-1-2-on-windows-server-2008-r2-and-iis-7-5/
3. https://support.laserfiche.com/kb/1013919/configuration-information-for-tls-1-2

Or, if you prefer, a time ago I'd wrote a script that can enable TLS 1.2 automatically for you: https://github.com/eduardomozart/ScriptUtil/tree/master/Scripts/Windows/EnableTLS12

Answer (score 0):

For "-2147467261 E_POINTER" and no value for "power of the key" when you ask for a user certificate, try with an old Web browser (Firefox 35.0).
For me, it was the solution.